# Dressed vs Dressing?

Tags: verbs

> Dressed in black, everyone attended his funeral.
>
> Dressing up in black, everyone attended his funeral.

Is dressed and dressing interchangeable? They both seem ok to me.

Comment: "Dressed" is by far a better choice as far as attending a funeral goes. You don't really want to be changing your attire while the eulogy is underway...

Comment: Is "Dressing in black" or "Dressed up in black" ok? What's the differences?

Comment: "Dressing up in black" is a *present* participle clause.  See http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses for explanations.  Which (of the four) do you think it fits?  BTW, past participle clause are also described there.

Comment: @VictorBazarov  So the first sentence mean he is "being dressed" by someone? And the second mean he dressed himself? If it does then I think it is interchangeable.

Comment: Not necessarily "by someone"?  By themselves is included.

Comment: If I say "I was dressed in red", does it mean that somebody else dressed me?

Comment: @VictorBazarov So is Dressing in black or Dressed up in black OK?

Comment: I still don't think that present participle is a good choice (with or without the "up").

Comment: @VictorBazarov So is dressed up proper? And if forgetting about its weirdness, is it literally ok to say dressing with or without up?

Comment: Let's see somebody else chime in, OK?  Somebody might be preparing an answer at this very moment...

Comment: "up" to me implies that they're dressing in a more formal manner than they usually do. I'm OK with either version (prefer "dressed") but the entire sentence is odd... I don't believe I'd ever put the "dressed/ing in black" as the first part of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

@Victor's comment on the question is accurate:

> "Dressed" is by far a better choice as far as attending a funeral goes. You don't really want to be changing your attire while the eulogy is underway...

In the context you've provided, "dressing" implies activity, i.e. zipping up during the eulogy.

The other context to consider is the future. E.G.

```
Q. What are you wearing to the Halloween party?
A. We're dressing as Lucy and Ricky
```

Meaning that in the future, when the couple attends, they *will be dressed* as a couple from a 50's sitcom.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, they are not interchangeable. As you can see from your two examples, you need to add additional words to your second sentence in order to create the same meaning. To be interchangeable, you could use either without the need for extraneous verbiage to get your point across.

> Dressed in black, everyone attended his funeral.

Quick and to the point - no quibbling to be done here.

> Dressing in black, everyone attended his funeral.

Were they getting dressed **as** they arrived? Did the funeral have **getting dressed** as a *theme*, where at certain points in the procession additional articles of clothing were put on?

Not interchangeable at all...